# Enum.HasFlag in Entity Framework Core for string-enum

Tags: c#, enums, entity-framework-core

I have a Customer entity/table in Entity Framework Core setup with an enum property named Mode. In the ModelBuilder, I have set so that it is saved as string in the database:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerEntity>()
    .Property(e => e.Mode)
    .HasConversion(
        v => v.ToString().ToUpper(),
        v => (CustomerEntity.CustomerMode)Enum.Parse(typeof(CustomerEntity.CustomerMode), v, true));
```

I get an error when I try to query for Customers:

```
var test = _appDbContext.Customers.Where(
    e => e.Mode.HasFlag(CustomerEntity.CustomerMode.OPERATIONAL| CustomerEntity.CustomerMode.STARTUP)).ToList();
```

The full exception:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The data types nvarchar and nvarchar are incompatible in the '&' operator.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(Enumerator enumerator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<>c.<MoveNext>b__19_0(DbContext _, Enumerator enumerator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MySolution.Backend.Api.Controllers.CustomersController.GetCustomers(Nullable`1 page, Nullable`1 pageSize, String search, String orderBy, String mode) in C:\Users\Me\source\repos\Backend\MySolution.Backend.Api\Controllers\CustomersController.cs:line 61
   at lambda_method83(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.

EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
ClientConnectionId:9ae128e5-3c92-41d4-93eb-2be95d072ddb
Error Number:402,State:1,Class:16
```

Assuming this exception is expected, is there any way to get my query to work with the HasFlag method without splitting up the Linq query into an "or"?

Comment: If I wrote it correctly, it gives the same exception ----- var test = _appDbContext.Customers.Where(e => (e.Mode & (CustomerEntity.CustomerMode.OPERATIONAL | CustomerEntity.CustomerMode.STARTUP)) == (CustomerEntity.CustomerMode.OPERATIONAL | CustomerEntity.CustomerMode.STARTUP)).ToList();

Comment: If you're doing a enum flag then you should save it as a number in the DB.  That's because if you have a flag `A= 1` and `B = 2` then `A | B` is 3 and the `ToString` will be "3" while values of 1 and 2 would be "A" and "B" respectively thus mixing names and numeric values.

Comment: And even then I'm not certain you can do `HasFlag` in an EF query.  You might just have to create the values you want to check for and do equality checks instead.  Like `var expected = A | B;` and then `Where(x => x.Enum == expected)`

Comment: There are a couple of other StackOverflow questions that states it would have worked had my DB column been an int, so I assume it will work with EFC that way. It is one of the options I am left with if what I asked for is not possible. Thanks for the explanation though, I can understand it if it is not possible to do it the way I initially wanted, I just hoped EFC would have some kind of built-in method to handle it.

Comment: The `ToString()` representation of `A | B` is `"A, B"` not the numeric value, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/sVC9xd.  For a flag with many bits set, the string representation could be very long -- with up to 32 values included for an `int` type enum.

Comment: @dbc Yeah when I tested that I forgot the `[Flags]` attribute.